# Combine Queries and Optimize PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a script that is as lean as possible.  The current implementation takes 20 minutes to process 3k records.
I wrote a quick and dirty script that processed the same info in about 90 seconds.  I now have to pull config info, and a bunch of other stuff, so I'm trying to optimize everything that I can.

Here is what I have now:

```
$key_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501 AND configuration_key = 'RCS_SKIP_DAYS';");
if (!$key_query) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$key = mysql_fetch_array($key_query);
$skip_days = $key['configuration_value'];
mysql_free_result($key_query);

$key_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501 AND configuration_key = 'RCS_BASE_DAYS';");
if (!$key_query) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$key = mysql_fetch_array($key_query);
$base_days = $key['configuration_value'];
mysql_free_result($key_query);

$key_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501 AND configuration_key = 'RCS_EMAIL_TTL';");
if (!$key_query) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$key = mysql_fetch_array($key_query);
$ttl_days = $key['configuration_value'];
mysql_free_result($key_query);

$skip_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$skip_days.' day',time()));
$base_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$base_days.' day',time()));
$ttl_date =  date('Ymd',strtotime('-'.$ttl_days.' day',time()));
```

I wasn't sure if it was possible to pull the 3 config keys together and assign to variables, or if there was a better way to optimize this.

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: `...AND configuration_key IN ('RCS_SKIP_DAYS', 'RCS_BASE_DAYS', 'RCS_EMAIL_TTL')`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you have a solution where you are cutting & pasting code and changing one little bit of code in each pasted piece of code, you are almost certainly doing it wrong.  You should look at hoisting repeated code into functions.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into `IN` syntax yet? It's pretty sweet. Also definitely no need for `SELECT * FROM` if you only need a few fields

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT configuration_key , configuration_value FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501 AND configuration_key IN ('RCS_SKIP_DAYS','RCS_BASE_DAYS','RCS_EMAIL_TTL')";

$query = mysqli_query($sql);

while(mysqli_fecth_assoc($query) as $row){
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Good call on the *, I forgot about that, I'm usually better at catching those.  I knew I could do the IN, but I wasn't sure how to assign them to specific variables.  I think I figured that out though.

Answer (score 3):

For first that to stop using this mysql_query this function is deprecated, try to use mysql pdo or mysql li

[Mysql PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [Mysqlli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Next step you maybe want change "`select *` ", its a big process cost, try to specify the columns you want to select.

Comment: PDO is immeasurably better than `mysql_query`, but a database layer that's more like an ORM would be better still. [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/) and [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) are two good examples of that.

Comment: Good to know that @tadman, i'm still learing about PHP persistent, i'll try some of that ORM, thanks

Comment: The MySQL PDO and Mysqlli are new to me.  I haven't done much php in years and I will doing a little copy/paste from some old reports on our server to use as a template.  Could you point me to some basic info with samples?  Similar to what MonkeyZeus did (but his threw an error for me)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get all the data in a single query and then filter it:

```
$key_query = "SELECT configuration_key , configuration_value FROM configuration WHERE configuration_group_id = 6501      AND configuration_key = 'RCS_SKIP_DAYS' OR configuration_key = 'RCS_BASE_DAYS' or configuration_key = 'RCS_EMAIL_TTL';"
```

Also it seems that you are only looking a configuration_value, so just ask for that column.

As suggested, use the latest MySQL PDO drivers.

Comment: -1 for use mysql_query fuction. Look for Mysql PDO.

Comment: Although `mysql_query` was present in the original question, if you're just talking about the query, post only the SQL part to avoid confusion.